# Copying image between the sheets with instant resizing & adjusting

Tags: excel, vba

I have got a problem.
I would like to copy the image between the Excel sheets and have it adjusted at once to the cells.

So far I managed perfectly with adjustment on the 1 sheet

```
  Sub signature()
  Dim myImage As Shape
  Dim imageWidth As Double
  Dim imageHeight As Double

  Set myImage = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 13")
  imageWidth = 170
  imageHeight = 65

  myImage.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
  myImage.Width = imageWidth
  myImage.Height = imageHeight

  'x:
  myImage.Left = myImage.Left + 650

  'y:
  myImage.Top = myImage.Top - 70

  End Sub
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

To the image is assigned the ID, as shown below:

[image]

Now, I want to copy this image into another 2 sheets, which can be done by this solution:

```
 Sub signature_copy()
   Sheets("Sign Off Sheet").Shapes("Picture 13").Copy
   Sheets("BoQ Civils").Range("C43").PasteSpecial
   Sheets("BoQ Cabling").Range("C37").PasteSpecial

 End Sub
```

Everything would be fine, but I am receiving an image of the same size.

[image]

It has to be fitted with the cells. Technically it's feasible by using the code above and changing the shape ID into the new one copied. Unfortunately, I can't do this, since I would like to use one image and make it copied & resized instantly in all sheets.

What should I do to receive this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sheets("Sign Off Sheet").Shapes("Picture 13").Copy
>
> Sheets("BoQ Civils").Range("C43").PasteSpecial

Work with Objects. It will be easier to handle them

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim shpA As Shape, shpB As Shape
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set shpA = Sheets("Sign Off Sheet").Shapes("Picture 13")
    shpA.Copy
    
    Set rng = Sheets("BoQ Civils").Range("C43")
    Sheets("BoQ Civils").Paste Destination:=rng
    
    Set shpB = Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes("Picture 13")
    
    With shpB
        .Top = rng.Top
        .Left = rng.Left
        .Width = rng.Width
        .Height = rng.Height
    End With
End Sub
```

**Edit**: If the shape name is getting renamed after copying it across then use `Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes.Count` to work with the shape as @Plutian suggested in the chat

```
Set shpB = Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes(Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes.Count)
```

Comment: Good answer, but using `.With` and `.Height` like this will destroy the aspect ratio and display a skewed signature. I propose to use `.Scaleheight` instead as per my answer.

Comment: True but user doesn't want to preserve it ;) See this in the question.  `myImage.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse`

Comment: Touché, but if I see the picture OP posted it seems like a bad idea not to.

Comment: It would work, but I am getting an error:  
Run-time-error The item with the specified name wasn't found.
And I know, where the problem is. Your code copies the image into the next sheet, which ID changes from "Image 13" to i.e "Image 19". Is there some solution to make this command more flexible for the image ID's?

Comment: If the user wants to preserve the aspect then yes, this method is not for him @Plutian

Comment: @MariuszKrukar: Which line?

Comment: Set shpB = Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes("Picture 13"), since my newly copied image has ID "Picture 21". This is the reason of problem.

Comment: @MariuszKrukar: I am guessing you are using `Sheets("BoQ Civils").Range("C43").PasteSpecial`. Can you please try with `Sheets("BoQ Civils").Paste Destination:=rng` ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I am using your solution and error still appears.
The debug line is:
Set shpB = Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes("Picture 13")

Comment: I believe, that your code is right once we get over the shape ID

Comment: @MariuszKrukar: The above code is tried and tested. it doesn't paste and rename the shape. unless there is already a shape with that name. Is there any other shape there in the worksheet? If no then you can also use `Set shpB = Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes(1)`

Comment: I think, that using the array instead of the ID works better. However, for the future work, it would be nice for me to get the first solution working too. If you tested the code, I don't know what causes this problem then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206790/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-mariusz-krukar). @MariuszKrukar

Answer (score 1):

You can create a resize function

```
Sub Example2()
SizeToRange ActiveSheet.Pictures("Picture 13"), Range("C43:D43")
End Sub

Function SizeToRange(s, Target As Range)
s.Left = Target.Left
s.Top = Target.Top
s.Width = Target.Width
s.Height = Target.Height
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.Scaleheight` method to scale by the height of the target cell. This will keep the aspect ratio of the picture while resizing with the height of the cell. By the looks of your picture, the target cell might be wider or narrower than you want your picture to be.

```
Sub signature_copy()
Dim sh As Shape

    Sheets("Sign Off Sheet").Shapes("Picture 13").copy

    Sheets("BoQ Civils").Range("C43").PasteSpecial

    Set sh = Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes(Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes.Count)

    With sh
        .ScaleHeight Factor:=(.TopLeftCell.Height / .Height), RelativeToOriginalSize:=msoTrue
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: For your code I did:
Dim sh As Shape, sh1 As Shape

now I am getting an error:
Object variable or With block variable not set 
under the line:
sh1 Sheets("Sign Off Sheet").Shapes("Picture 13").Copy

Comment: Ah my error, I changed the layout slightly when typing my post. `Sh1` should be deleted. see revised answer.

Comment: It would work, but now I am getting an error:
The index of the specified collection is out of bounds

Comment: I would be much smarter if I would learn to read. `Set sh = Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes(Sheet2.Shapes.Count)` is wrong, it should be `Set sh = Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes(Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes.Count)` another remnant from when I changed the code from my test case.

Comment: ++ A very important piece of code if aspect needs to be maintained :)