# Delete specified image with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Continuing the operation raised in this issue:

[Copying image between the sheets with instant resizing & adjusting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59948073/copying-image-between-the-sheets-with-instant-resizing-adjusting/59948582?noredirect=1#comment106021488_59948582)

Now I would like to set an automatic on-click delete option for these newly copied images.

[image]

I have written the simple macro for this purpose:

```
  Sub Signature_remove()
  '
  ' Signature_remove Macro
  '


   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 49")).Select
   Selection.Delete
   Sheets("BoQ Civils").Select
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 72")).Select
   Selection.Delete
 End Sub
```

because it applies to 2 sheets.
Unfortunately it wasn't wise idea, because it returns the pictures ID in array, that are going to change as the process repeats.
In turn I cannot really use the

```
          Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes(Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes.Count)
```

because I am afraid, that all images placed in this sheet will be removed.

Is there any solution to delete these images quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me break this down:

```
Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes(Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes.Count)
```

`Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes.Count` will return number of images (shapes in general) you have in sheet `BoQ Civils`, so `Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes(Sheets("BoQ Civils").Shapes.Count)` will return image with the last index, so image, which was added last.

In turn, you are safe - you don't want delete all pictures in sheet, just the last one.

And this is what you after, from what I understand.